# Is the language {a,b,c} which words are divisible by 4 and the word start and ends with same letters is context free?

Tags: context-free-grammar

is the language above the {a,b,c} alphabet composed of words of length divisible by 4 starting and ending with the same letter context-free?
I tried doing it with  `Pumping lemma` but im not sure if i did it right.
So f.e i choosed word

```
z = abacbcaa
```

k = 2^3 = 8
Then i split z into z = uvwxy, f.e `z = a | b | ac | bc | aa`

1. vw != ϵ `true`
2. |vwx| <= k  `true`

Now i choose i = 2 so z would be

```
z = uv^2wx^2y = abbacbcbcaa
```

It turnded out that the lenght of this words i 11, so it's not Contex-Free? Did I do this right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try to write a regular expression for it.